# remove specific line from json with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this array:

```
var array = [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"3","b":"1"},{"a":"5","b":"4"}]
```

now i want to remove the line, lets say, where a=5. So afterwards the array looks like this:

```
var array = [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"3","b":"1"}]
```

How do i do this the easiest and fastest way?

Comment: BTW, that's not json, that's real javascript object.

Comment: The easiest and fastest way is always to use for loop and if clause. And then you probably want to read about [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [something else](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) which allows you to return null for an element to be deleted.

eg:

```
var array = [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"3","b":"1"},{"a":"5","b":"4"}]
var newArray = $.map(array, function(e){
   return (e.a == "5") ? null : e;
});
// newArray contains [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"3","b":"1"}]
```

Live example (watch the console): http://jsfiddle.net/2Yz7f/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (non jQuery) approach: http://jsfiddle.net/VYKBc/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your answer

```
array.splice(2,1);
```